# ViteJS + Laravel 10 error: Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions or html files

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vite

I can't run ViteJS on laravel 10. It tells me that it finds the entry point and does not run any script in the app.js. I'm using XAMPP and running laravel.

`vite.config.js`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

`login.blade.php`:

```php
 @vite(['/resources/js/app.js'])
```

`/resource/js/app.js`:

```js
import './bootstrap';

import '../assets/js/jquery.min.js';
```

Terminal:

```
npm run dev

> cmit@1.0.0 dev
> vite

`(!) Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions or html files and there are no explicit optimizeDeps.include patterns. Skipping dependency pre-bundling.

  VITE v4.4.11  ready in 494 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h to show help

  LARAVEL v10.28.0  plugin v0.8.1

  ➜  APP_URL: http://localhost/mysite`
```

I need to run the JS scripts I have using Vitejs but I can't do it.